# Make tuple of member function pointers in variadic template function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member, stdtuple

How can I get a tuple of member function pointers? I can't seem to find the right syntax. I thought this would work:

```
template <typename... T>
auto getPushBackFunctionPointers() -> std::tuple<void(std::vector<T>::*)(T const&)...>
{
    return std::make_tuple(&std::vector<T>::push_back...);
}
```

But it doesn't compile (GCC 4.8.2):

> error: too many arguments to function 'constexpr std::tuple::__type ...>
>   std::make_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {}]'
>        return std::make_tuple(&std::vector::push_back...);
>                                                           ^

I found a workaround by introducing a helper function like this:

```
template <typename T>
auto getPushBackFunctionPointer() -> void(std::vector<T>::*)(T const&)
{
    return &std::vector<T>::push_back;
}

template <typename... T>
auto getPushBackFunctionPointers() -> std::tuple<void(std::vector<T>::*)(T const&)...>
{
    return std::make_tuple(getPushBackPointer<T>()...);
}
```

Can I do this in a single function somehow?

Comment: What error are you getting with the first one?

Comment: `std::vector<T>::push_back` is overloaded, so you need to select an overload (this can be done with a cast). I think I remember there's also a problem with taking addresses of StdLib functions, maybe a StdLib implementation may have additional overloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @dyp in the comments, there is a problem of overload selection.  Your workaround works because there is only 1 `push_back` member function with the signature you want.  You can do it in one function using a cast

```
 template <typename... T>
    auto getPushBackFunctionPointers() -> std::tuple<void(std::vector<T>::*)(T const&)...>
    {

        return std::make_tuple(static_cast<void(std::vector<T>::*)(T const&)>(&std::vector<T>::push_back)...);
    }
```

Personally, I find the helper function which operates on one type more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

```
#define Return(ret) decltype(ret) { return ret; }

template <typename... T>
auto getPushBackFunctionPointers()
-> Return(std::tuple<void (std::vector<T>::*)(T const&)...>(&std::vector<T>::push_back...))
```